# In remix Ide getting error "You have not set a script to run. Set it with @custom:dev-run-script NatSpec tag" for a smart contract

Tags: blockchain, solidity, remix

I have created a smart contract CashFlow.sol which runs fine.

While creating another smart contract which imports CashFlow.sol I get error:
"You have not set a script to run. Set it with @custom:dev-run-script NatSpec tag"

I am selecting the correct smart contract while trying to compile the same.
Can anyone help on this please.

// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.8.2 <0.9.0;

/**

- @title CashFlowMerchant
- @dev To determine loan repayment
- @custom:dev-run-script ./scripts/deploy_with_ethers.ts
  */

import "./CashFlow.sol";

contract CashFlowMerchant {
CashFlow public cashFlow_ref;

```
uint public customerPaymentAmt = 0;
uint public loanSettlmntAmount;
uint public merchantAmtRecvd;
uint public bankEMI;

constructor(CashFlow _addrCashFlow,
uint _customerPaymentAmt) {
    cashFlow_ref = _addrCashFlow;
    customerPaymentAmt = _customerPaymentAmt;
}

function repayLoan() external {
    require(loanSettlmntAmount > 0, "No need to deduct amount");

    if (loanSettlmntAmount > 0 && customerPaymentAmt > 10){
    bankEMI = ((customerPaymentAmt * 10)/100);
            if(loanSettlmntAmount > bankEMI){
                merchantAmtRecvd = customerPaymentAmt - bankEMI;
            }else{
                bankEMI = bankEMI - loanSettlmntAmount;
                merchantAmtRecvd = customerPaymentAmt - bankEMI;
            }        
        }else{
            merchantAmtRecvd = customerPaymentAmt;
        }
    }

}
```